# UI Testing in Xcode 7: Selecting a row number in a UIPickerView / PickerWheel

Tags: xcode, swift, uipickerview, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way in Xcode 7 UI Testing to select the 3rd row in a UIPickerView?

I have tried various things like this to identify the rows in each picker but all the requests below return 0 found:

```
XCUIApplication().pickers.element.cells.count
XCUIApplication().pickers.element.staticTexts.count
```

Any ideas?

Updated: I am aware of adjustToPickerWheelValue method where you can select a particular value you already know, but I am trying to select the 3rd value (index = 4) when I don't know the values that exist in the picker.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-adjustToPickerWheelValue:` to select items on a `UIPickerView`.

When there is one `UIPickerView` on the screen you can select the element directly, like so.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
app.pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("Books")
```

If the picker has multiple wheels you will need to first select the wheel via it's accessibility identifier, then adjust it.

```
app.pickerWheels["Feet"].adjustToPickerWheelValue("5")
```

Here's a [GitHub repo with a working example](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UIPickerViewTester). And some [more information in a blog post I wrote](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-xcode-7/#interacting-with-pickers).

Comment: Apologies Joe.  My question was not fully clear.  I have updated it accordingly.

Comment: Please note there is a bug in current implementation of `adjustToPickerWheelValue`. There is a radar about it: http://www.openradar.me/22918650

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
let pickerWheel = XCUIApplication().pickers.pickerWheels.element
let appWindowHeight = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).frame.height
let pickerWheelCellHeight = GFloat(44)
    func advancePickerWheelOneValue() -> Self {
         let topScrollPoint = Double(pickerWheel.frame.midY/appWindowHeight)
         let bottomScrollPoint = Double((pickerWheel.frame.midY + pickerWheelCellHeight)/appWindowHeight)
         let topScreenPoint = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: topScrollPoint))
         let bottomScreenPoint = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: bottomScrollPoint))
         bottomScreenPoint.pressForDuration(0, thenDragToCoordinate: topScreenPoint)
         return self
    }
```

You may need to adjust the dx value depending on where the picker is.

```
.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5,
```

But 0.5 works if the picker occupies the width of the screen.

With this method you an move the picker on value at a time.  Call it multiple times and you get to the value you want.

Its not ideal but it can help if you want to check certain indexes.  Hopefully you would have to use it on a picker with hundreds of values ;)

Answer (score 0):

Example with Date picker (UIDatePicker)

[image]

```
 XCUIApplication().datePickers.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(0).adjustToPickerWheelValue("March")
 XCUIApplication().datePickers.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(1).adjustToPickerWheelValue("24")
 XCUIApplication().datePickers.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(2).adjustToPickerWheelValue("2000")
```

And here is example with Picker view (UIPickerView)

[image]

```
 XCUIApplication().pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("Male")
```